# 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext' is not defined in Web Applications (not web sites)

Tags: linq

In a Web Forms Web Application project, in both C# and VB, Linq2SQL is not working. I'm getting the error 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext' is not defined, and my Linq2SQL class will not compile. Well, that's not quite correct. The entire solution will compile, but if I try to open the default page, the error comes up, and if I look in the designer for the class, anything to do with Linq is underlined in red, and I can't reference the class.

Also, in the Imports of the Linq class, the compiler is telling me "Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Data.Linq' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found."

And if I create a Web Site project, there is no problem with Linq.

Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Can you upload somewhere some sample reproducing the problem

Comment: 1. Open Visual Studio 2015
2. Start a Web Application (Web forms) project
3. Add an app_code directory
4. Add a Linq2SQL class to the app_code directory

Either start the application or browse within VS to the default page.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue, found that the core problem was not having the web.config file in the root with the following node:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0,
                    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</configuration>
```

My understanding: the referencing issue arises as it's not including the Linq assembly in the build, so if you add the assembly, it works.